# The Localhost of visual studio doesn't show up when I have WAMP server installed. How do you make it work?

Tags: php, visual-studio-2008, wamp

I've first installed the WAMP server on my system.
It used http://localhost to show my files in the www directory.

But then I installed visual studio 2008. It too uses the http://localhost/
But it doesn't show up. What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean IIS? Cassini (the build in "debugging" webserver) uses high ports when you fire an app up. Either way you need to configure either WAMP or IIS to listen on a port other than port 80, then you can access one on http://localhost/ and one on http://localhost:MYPORT/.

Comment: You can run something from Cassini without having to edit WAMP's ports; so if they aren't planning to use IIS they don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

VS uses it's own development server, and usually VS starts his own server in debug mode, and there isn't a common server executable. Since VS needs to start it's own server in debug mode to test .NET driven applications, it can't show your WAMP applications because it usually runs in other port. Also, you can't run PHP applications under VS.

Try looking at server connection that the browser brings you at the application URL.